# Nested model forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to setup a simple nested model form but I am getting an error when trying to display the form via the 'new' action.  Here is my setup:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :people
    has_many :organizations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account

    has_many :locations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class AccountsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @account = Account.new
        @account.organizations.build
    end

    def create
        @account = Account.new(params[:account])
        if @account.save
            #handle success
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

end

<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :type %><br />
<%= f.text_field :type %><br />

    <%= f.fields_for :organization do |organization_fields| %>
        <%= organization_fields.label :name %><br />
        <%= organization_fields.text_field :name %><br />
        <%= organization_fields.label :website %><br />
        <%= organization_fields.text_field :website %><br />
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Add account" %>
<% end %>
```

When attempting to hit the 'new' action at /accounts/new I am getting the following error:

uninitialized constant Account::Organization

Application Trace:
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:5:in 'new'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an odd load order problem. Are you doing anything clever with config.load_paths or anything like that?

Just for the sake of seeing if it makes it work, try `require File.join(Rails.root, 'app/models/organization.rb')` at the top of account.rb. This is not a solution you want to keep around, but if it works with that line then you'll know the problem is with the loader.

Comment: I found my error.  In my Organization model, I added accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations and it works.  Silly mistake.  Thanks for your help.